# Why does one interface implementation require a cast while another does not?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, covariance

I was doing some work with interfaces today, when I run into the following scenario. Given these two simple interfaces:

```
public interface IItem { }
public interface IInventory
{
    ICollection<IItem> Items { get; }
}
```

I made a simple class to implement `IInventory`, and noticed that this implementation is perfectly fine as written:

```
public class BasicInventory1 : IInventory
{
    private Dictionary<int, IItem> items;
    public ICollection<IItem> Items
    {
        get { return items.Values; }
    }
}
```

But yet, this implementation requires a cast:

```
public class BasicInventory2 : IInventory
{
    private Dictionary<int, IItem> items;
    public ICollection<IItem> Items
    {
        get { return (ICollection<IItem>)items; }
    }
}
```

Why does one require a cast and the other doesn't? Checking the object typing for both collections that are getting returned in either case confirms that they both in fact implement `ICollection`.

I suspect there is some magic type conversions going on under the hood here, and therefore seems to have something to do with co/contravariance, but I don't quite see what exactly is going on.

Comment: In `BasicInventory2` you return the complete dictionary, not the collection of the values. And I think that your cast would fail at run-time.

Comment: A `Dictionary<K, V>` is not an `ICollection<V>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dictionary<int, IItem>` does not implement `ICollection<IItem>`. Simple as that.

It wouldn't make sense to implement that interface because you cannot add to a dictionary without specifying a key. The interface does not make sense.

This is a runtime error because items could refer to a subclass of Dictionary so that the cast might be valid.

Comment: And therefore the cast is actually a runtime error is it not?

Comment: @Charleh yes it should be because `items` could refer to a subclass of `Dictionary`.

Comment: Well if that were the case it wouldn't be a runtime error or a compile time error (and you wouldn't need the cast because at design time the compiler would know that the subclass implemented `ICollection<V>`) but in the OPs case we can see it's not a subclassed dict so it would be a runtime invalid cast

Comment: @Charleh for the compiler the static type decides. The runtime cast uses the runtime type.

Comment: Which in this case is `ICollection<K, V>` not `ICollection<V>` so it would result in an invalid cast because the user is using a `Dictionary<K, V>` not a subclass of dictionary, but yes, they could implement `ICollection<V>` in a subclass but I'm not sure why you'd want to when `Dictionary<K,V>.Values` already returns `ICollection<V>`

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you were to add `.Values` to the second example, you would not need the cast

```
public class BasicInventory2 : IInventory
{
    private Dictionary<int, IItem> items;
    public ICollection<IItem> Items
    {
       get { return items.Values; }
    }
}
```

This is because items is a Dictionary and that implements `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

Comment: This would make both examples identical though, so that’s unlikely the purpose ;)

Answer (score 0):

In `BasicInventory1` you return `items.Values` in `BasicInventory2` you return only `items`.
`.Values` returns a `ICollection`, so no cast is need.

MSDN:

- [Dictonary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This code is NOT VALID and will always generate a runtime error:

```
    public class BasicInventory2 : IInventory
    {
        private Dictionary<int, IItem> items = new Dictionary<int, IItem>();

        public ICollection<IItem> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return (ICollection<IItem>) items;
            }
        }
    }
```

A  `Dictionary<int, IItem>` does NOT implement `ICollection<IItem>`, whereas the type returned from `Dictionary<int, IItem>.Values` *does*.

So the answer is:

The first case is ok because `Values` is of the correct type.

In the second case, the compiler knows that you are trying to return the wrong type and so it gives you a compile error.

If you override the error with a case, you will get a runtime `BadCastException`.

Comment: My apologies for the bad form. It compiled so I assumed it worked.

Answer (score -1):

In the second code you use the dictionary as return value where in the first code you use the values. `Dictionary<int,IItems>` inherits from `ICollection<KeyValuePair<int,IItems>>` thus is not `ICollection<IItems>`. Therefore you need the cast.

Comment: `ICollection` has only one generic parameter, not two.